# Algorithm to find first sum of an array within a range

Tags: c#, algorithm

I'm have a fairly complicated (to me) algorithm that I'm trying to write.  The idea is to determine which elements in an array are the first ones to sum up to a value that falls within a range.

For example:

I have an array `[1, 15, 25, 22, 25]` that is in a prioritized order.

I want to find the first set of values with the most elements that sum within a minimum and maximum range, not necessarily the set that get me closest to my max.

So, if the min is 1 and max is 25, I would select `[0(1), 1(15)]` even though the third element `[2(25)]` is closer to my max of 25 because those come first.

If the min is 25 and max is 40, I would select `[0(1), 1(15), 3(22)]`, skipping the third element since that would breach the max.

If the min is 50 and max is 50, I would select `[2(25), 4(25)]` since those are the only two that can meet the min and max requirements.

Are there any common CS algorithms that match this pattern?

Comment: The exact goal is somewhat unclear to me. In the first case, why not simply take [0(1)]? In the second case, why not take [2(25)] or [0(1), 2(25)] or [1(15), 2(25)]?

Comment: I added a clarification.  I want to get the most elements as well. So even thought the first element satisfies the min/max, I want to keep counting to get the most elements within the parameters.

Comment: So, you want to find the largest subset of elements in your list such that their sum falls within a given range.

Comment: Correct, but the kicker is that it should be the "first" set.  Meaning I'd take a set of 2 elements that fall within the range instead of a set of 3 elements, if the set of 2 were closer to the beginning of the array.

Comment: for the first example why not [0(1), 3(22)] an answer? It satisfies the min, max better than [0(1), 1(15)]

Comment: So if there exist solutions that include the first element, the correct answer is limited to those solutions... otherwise, if there are solutions that include the second, the answer is limited to those... etc. And, perhaps, if there are two solutions that have the same number of elements, the one whose elements appear earlier must be preferred.

Comment: @SomeDude because [0(1), 1(15)] are "higher priority" while still satisfying the min/max

Comment: @Patrick87 yes, that's correct.  This is being applied to a queuing priority use case, so the elements are in order of preference to be used.

Answer (score 0):

This is a dynamic programming problem.

You want to build a data structure to answer the following question.

```
by next to last position available in the array:
    by target sum:
        (elements in sum, last position used)
```

When it finds a target_sum in range, you just read back through it to get the answer.

Here is pseudocode for that.  I used slightly Pythonish syntax and JSON to represent the data structure.  Your code will be longer:

```
Initialize the lookup to [{0: (0, null)}]
for i in 1..(length of array):
    # Build up our dynamic programming data structure
    Add empty mapping {} to end of lookup
    best_sum = null
    best_elements = null
    for prev_sum, prev_elements, prev_position in lookup for i-1:
        # Try not using this element
        if prev_sum not in lookup[i] or lookup[i][prev_sum][0] < prev_elements:
            lookup[i][prev_sum] = (prev_elements, prev_position)

        # Try using this element
        next_sum = prev_sum + array[i-1]
        next_elements = prev_elements + 1
        prev_position = i-1
        if next_sum not in lookup lookup[i][next_sum][0] < prev_elements:
            lookup[i][next_sum] = (next_elements, next_position)
        if next_sum in desired range:
            if best_elements is null or best_elements < this_elements
                best_elements = this_elements
                best_sum = this_sum

    if best_elements is not null:
        # Read out the answer!
        answer = []
        j = i
        while j is not null:
            best_sum = lookup[j][0]
            answer.append(array[j])
            j = lookup[j][1]
        return reversed(answer)
```

This will return the desired values rather than the indexes.  To switch, just reverse what goes into the `answer`.